# Remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop') only pages

Tags: pages

I would like to apply these two functions that remove `<p>`

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

I would like it to only apply to wordpress pages. In the articles I would like to have them. How to do it?

I hope they can help me, I just start programming topics in wordpress.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the_content filter apply to all posts which means pages and articles. What you can do is to add condition to its execution.

First you remove filter as you did

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

then you add another filter that will call the wpautop function depending on a test like this :

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
  if(/* you test if it's an article or whatever you want*/)
       $content = wpautop($content);
  return $content; 
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

like this you may control if the wpautop is called or not depending on your condition.

You do the same for **the_excerpt**

Comment: In the 2nd instance, I think you mean `add_filter`, not `remove_filter`

Comment: @socki03 oh yes ! updated :) (bad copy/paste)

Comment: Dear,

Thank you for your prompt response and your help.
I forgot to tell you that I do not really program, nothing :( .How would I do if I wanted to apply this filter only for the pages?

Comment: you may add this inside the if `$post->post_type === 'post'` and before the if add this instruction `global $post`

Comment: the function should look like this `function my_the_content_filter($content) {
global $post;  
if($post->post_type === 'post')
       $content = wpautop($content);
  return $content; 
}`